# Is it possible to filter search by programming language without using tags?

Tags: support, search

I'm only coding in Ruby, I'd like to search for answer for this language only.

I can filter using the ruby tag, but posters don't seem to consistently use them. Any better option?

Comment: Kill anyone who doesn't use the tag?

Comment: Good idea, but I'm trying to find quick answers...and killing them all will take me too much time, we're quite a bit in here. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm, so we can't weed out people who don't consistently use Ruby tags, and we can't really identify Ruby questions definitively unless they have a Ruby tag... I guess you're screwed.

Comment: I guess I am...thus my question !

Comment: I dunno nuttin bout Ruby other than it stinks of PHP, so I can't really help... Hey!  You know Ruby!  Tell me, what other combination of tags only apply to Ruby development?

Comment: ruby, rails, ror, sinatra...

Comment: Ever try to filter your search using rals or ror or sinatra?

Comment: Yep, but it misses the not-tagged answers...

Comment: Look, I'm going to break it to you... if people hide their questions, you're likely not to find them.  But, look on the bright side--these idiots are maybe 10% of the questions out there.  And probably 90% of them need to be closed.  So, in the end, it doesn't even matter.  Linkin Park.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This seems a bit specific to Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should have asked at [their Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).)*

Tags really is the proper way to identify the topic of a post. If someone doesn't tag it appropriately, they run the risk of having their question missed by someone who could otherwise answer it.

You could search for "[ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby)" to try to find posts where the word is used but perhaps the tag isn't, but because it's a single word and a tag exists for it, the search defaults to doing a tag search in any case.

Perhaps a tag wildcard search would be more helpful. Searching for `[ruby*]` will get anything tagged 'ruby', 'ruby-1.8.7', 'ruby-on-rails', 'ruby-datamapper', etc.

Since you're looking for answers, rather than questions to answer, I think it's fine to rely on the tags. Even if the asker didn't know enough to use the appropriate tag(s), the answerer almost certainly did and should have added the tag.

Comment: thanks @Fish Below the Ice , and sorry for posting in the wrong meta...